# How to calculate C1- and C2-Continuity of Bezier-Curve?

Tags: graphing-functions, bezier-curve

I have the following example I don't understand.

Here is a Bezier-Curve over *[0, 1]* with the following setup
[image: Bezier Curve]

Now the example explains how to construct the other Bezier-Curve, which connects to point (2,2) with a C2-Continuity, over *[1, 2]*.

(This is in German. "Stetigkeit" stands for continuity. Sorry about that)

[image]

Generally I know about

- Calculate the length of the two intervals (1 and 1 each)
- The positions of p1,2 and p2,2 are relative to the length of the intervals.

But I don't understand how to calculate them by pure math-

Answer (score 5):

The description presented looks confusing,
so here is one possible interpretation,
if the subject is about 
making a $C_2$ connection 
of the two cubic Bezier curves (segments).

The expression

\begin{align} 
s_1(t)&=
 B_0^3(t)\left[\begin{matrix}0\\ 0\end{matrix}\right]
+B_1^3(t)\left[\begin{matrix}0\\ 1\end{matrix}\right]
+B_2^3(t)\left[\begin{matrix}1\\ 2\end{matrix}\right]
+B_3^3(t)\left[\begin{matrix}2\\ 2\end{matrix}\right]
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}

defines the coordinates of a point 
$s_1(t)$ 
for any $t\in[0,1]$
on the first cubic Bezier curve (segment)
with control points

\begin{align} 
p_{01}&=(0,0)
,\quad
p_{11}=(0,0)
,\quad
p_{21}=(1,2)
,\quad
p_{31}=(2,2)
,
\end{align}
where, for example, $p_{21}=(1,2)$
means that 
$x$-coordinate of 
of the point $p_{21}$ is $1$,
and its $y$-coordinate is $2$.

Points $p_{0k}$ and $p_{3k}$
are always located on the endpoints  of the curve.
The other two points $p_{1k}$ and $p_{2k}$
usually are not on the curve,
but they control the shape of the curve.

Next, $B_k^3(t)$ means 
$k$-th cubic 
[Bernstein polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial),

\begin{align} 
B_k^3(t)&=\textstyle\binom{3}{k}(1-t)^{3-k}t^k
,\\
B_0^3(t)&=(1-t)^3
,\quad
B_1^3(t)=3(1-t)^2t
,\quad
B_2^3(t)=3(1-t)t^2
,\quad
B_3^3(t)=t^3
.
\end{align}

Thus, the expression \eqref{1}
can be written in a general form 
for the $k$-th segment as

\begin{align} 
s_k(t)&=
(1-t)^3 p_{0k}
+3(1-t)^2t\cdot p_{1k}
+3(1-t)t^2\cdot p_{2k}
+t^3\cdot p_{3k}
\tag{2}\label{2}
,
\end{align}

which in fact represents two expressions (in 2D), 
for $x$ and $y$-coordinates of the point $s_k(t)$ 
on the $k$-th Bezier segment

\begin{align} 
s_{kx}(t)&=
(1-t)^3 p_{0kx}
+3(1-t)^2t\cdot p_{1kx}
+3(1-t)t^2\cdot p_{2kx}
+t^3\cdot p_{3kx}
,\\
s_{ky}(t)&=
(1-t)^3 p_{0ky}
+3(1-t)^2t\cdot p_{1ky}
+3(1-t)t^2\cdot p_{2ky}
+t^3\cdot p_{3ky}
,
\end{align}

which are just ordinary cubic polynomials in terms of parameter $t$.

Note that for any segment the parameter 
$t$ (often called as time parameter) runs from
$t=0$ (point $p_{0k}$)
to
$t=1$ (point $p_{3k}$).

The sequence of such connected segments $s_k$ is often called 
a cubic Bezier spline 
(don't confuse it with B-splines!),
and the word "spline" suggests that these segments 
are connected smoothly, 
which this exercise was supposed to demonstrate.

What is missing in the original illustration, 
are the two actual cubic Bezier segments,
which are smoothly connected:

[image]

So, the instructions tell us that
given the first cubic Bezier segment $s_1$
which is defined by control points 
$p_{01}$ through $p_{31}$,
we can smoothly 
(that is, the resulting two-segment curve will be $C_2$-continuous) 
extend the curve with segment $s_2$,
by calculating three of its control points, 
$p_{02},p_{12}$ and $p_{22}$. 
The last control point can be chosen freely,
its location does not affect 
the smoothness of the curve $s_1,s_2$
(in fact, the point $p_{01}$ can be chosen freely as well).

In order to get the $C_2$-continuity, we need first ensure 
$C_0$, that is, the starting point 
$p_{02}$ of the second segment 
must coincide with the endpoint $p_{31}$ of the first:

\begin{align} 
p_{02}&=p_{31}
,\\
\text{or }\quad
s_1(1)&=s_2(0)
.
\end{align}

To get $C_1$-continuity, we need 
to guarantee that

\begin{align} 
s'_1(t)|_{t=1}&=s'_2(t)|_{t=0}
,\\
\text{which gives }\quad
p_{12} &= 2p_{31}-p_{21}
\end{align}

The last condition for $C_2$--continuity is

\begin{align} 
s''_1(t)|_{t=1}&=s''_2(t)|_{t=0}
,\\
\text{which gives }\quad
p_{22} &= p_{11}+2p_{12}-2p_{21}
.
\end{align}
Also, note that the phrase
"$\dots$ which connects to point $(2,2)$ 
with a $C_2$-continuity, over $[1, 2]$"
is incorrect.
The second segment (the actual curve)
smoothly connects the endpoint $p_{31}$
of the first segment $s_1$
with the endpoint $p_{32}$ 
of the second segment $s_2$,
and not "over $[1, 2]$",
but still "over $[0, 1]$",
that is, $t\in[0,1]$.
Even if, for example, this two-segment curve 
represents a smooth trajectory of the point
for some timeline $T$ and
we assume that
the segment $s_1$ starts at $T=0$
and ends at $T=1$, 
then $s_2$ follows and ends at $T=2$,
we still have to use $t$ from 0 to 1
to calculate the points 
according to \eqref{2}.

**Edit**

In case if we would like to use 
a global time parameter $T$
to control the smooth movement of the point
using given sequence of "time points", 
we need to use modified expression 
for the point on the curve.

Since cubic Bezier curves are defined
for local time parameter $t\in[0,1]$,
we need to modify the procedure
of the smooth connection of the two segments 
by using a transformation 
from the global $T$,
starting time $T=t_k$
and ending time $T=t_{k+1}$
for the segment $s_k$:
\begin{align}
t&=\tfrac{T-t_k}{t_{k+1}-t_k}
.
\end{align}

Then we have the expression 
for the coordinated of the point 
on the segment $s_k$ as

\begin{align}
s_k(T)
&=
 (1-\tfrac{T-t_k}{t_{k+1}-t_k})^3\cdot p_{0k}
\\
&+3\cdot(1-\tfrac{T-t_k}{t_{k+1}-t_k})^2(\tfrac{T-t_k}{t_{k+1}-t_k})\cdot p_{1k}
\\
&+3\cdot(1-\tfrac{T-t_k}{t_{k+1}-t_k})(\tfrac{T-t_k}{t_{k+1}-t_k})^2\cdot p_{2k}
\\
&+(\tfrac{T-t_k}{t_{k+1}-t_k})^3\cdot p_{3k}
.
\end{align}

Given that, we can find the control points 
of the smoothly attached segment $s_{k+1}$,
which has assigned global time length $t_{k+2}-t_{k+1}$,
that satisfy three conditions of continuity:

\begin{align}
s_{k+1}(T)|_{T=t_{k+1}}&=s_{k}(T)|_{T=t_{k+1}}
,\\
s'_{k+1}(T)|_{T=t_{k+1}}&=s'_{k}(T)|_{T=t_{k+1}}
,\\
s''_{k+1}(T)|_{T=t_{k+1}}&=s''_{k}(T)|_{T=t_{k+1}}
.
\end{align}

This system results in
\begin{align}
p_{0\,k+1}&=p_{1\,k}
,\\
p_{1\,k+1}&=
p_{3\,k}-
\tfrac{t_{k+2}-t_{k+1}}{t_{k+1}-t_k}\cdot(p_{2\,k}-p_{3\,k})
,\\
p_{2\,k+1}&=
2p_{1\,k+1}-p_{3\,k}
+(\tfrac{t_{k+2}-t_{k+1}}{t_{k+1}-t_k})^2\cdot(p_{1\,k}-2\,p_{2\,k}+p_{3\,k})
.
\end{align}

Back to the OP: assuming we have

\begin{align}
t_0&=0
,\quad 
t_{1}=1
,\quad
t_{2}=3
. 
\end{align}

Then the control points of the extension curve $q_2$ would be
\begin{align}
q_{02}&=p_{31}
,\\
q_{12}&=3\,p_{31}-2\,p_{21}
,\\
q_{22}&=4\,p_{11}-12\,p_{21}+9\,p_{31}
.
\end{align}

And since we still can choose any point as $q_{32}$,
let $q_{32}=p_{32}$, so we can compare
the two extension segments, which differ 
in the time span: for the first one we have 
$t_1=1$, $t_2=2$, and
for the second one we have 
$t_1=1$, $t_2=3$.

Here is the difference:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how would the calculation for C2 change, if the second interval would be [1, 3]?

Comment: @Saphire:
What exactly do you mean by 
"interval would be $[1, 3]$"?
Interval of what?
Every cubic Bezier segment
is defined specifically
to use the local time parameter $t\in[0,1]$.
And the described instructions are 
making a smooth ($C_2$) extension 
for the given Bezier segment
with another one.

Comment: I'm sorry. I mean if the interval for the points which are supposed to be created for a C2-Curve would be [1,3] instead of [1, 2]. In this example both intervals have the length of 1, but what if the second curve should be created over [1,3]? That would change the length.

Comment: @Saphire: We can always smoothly extend
our two-segment spline $\{s_1,s_2\}$
with the third segment, $s_3$,
using exactly the same instructions
to get $p_{03},p_{13},p_{23}$
from known $p_{12},p_{22},p_{32}$.
Then we can consider that 
the global time parameter $T$
of our three-segment cubic Bezier spline
$\{s_1,s_2,s_3\}$
varies from $0$ to $3$, while
the local time parameter $t$
changes from $0$ to $1$ for every
segment $s_1,s_2,s_3$.

Comment: @Saphire: Please, check out the update - is that what you are after?

Comment: @g.kov.  Good answer. However, your statement that  "Every cubic Bezier segment is defined specifically to use the local time parameter $t∈[0,1]$ is dubious, at best. Bezier segments often use parameter intervals different from $[0,1]$. For example, the Bezier segments in a NURBS curve use various different parameter intervals. Also, the concept of blossoming relies on the use of arbitrary parameter intervals.

Comment: @bubba: 
Well, its all about definitions.
By the way, 
NURBS =
Non-Uniform RATIONAL BASIS Spline =
is much more complex in many ways
and completely different beast
than the simple cubic Bezier curve segment,
which definition is in Eq.(1).
Cubic Bezier segment
is completely defined by four ordered control points, say,
$p_0,p_1,p_2,p_3$
and everybody know that when the local time parameter $t$
varies from $0$ to $1$, 
the point moves from
$p_0$ to $p_3$
along the curve (segment).
There is just no place for $t$
outside the range $[0,1]$, by definition.

Comment: @bubba:Of course, we can conveniently 
use any values for the global time $T$,
as shown above, but the LOCAL 
$t=\tfrac{T-t_k}{t_{k+1}-t_k}$
is always in $[0,1]$.