# Formula or Algorithm to Draw curved lines between points

Tags: algorithms, curves

I'm developing a script to connect point with curved lines.

The points are in ascendent order in x-axis like this:

[image]

I'm studying **Bezier Curves**, but I don't think it's the best solution (see https://www.geogebra.org/m/qcnExXbn):

[image]

But, instead of straight lines, I just would like to connect these points in a smooth way.

Could anyone help me with a formula or algorithm?

Comment: Why have you decided Bezier curves (aka cubic splines) are not what you want? It's good enough for Postscript's CurveTo...

Comment: Is this close to what you're looking for? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation

Comment: @David C. Ullrich I'm not wanting to use Bezier Curves because I need the line to "touch" the point and the Bezier Curve will just stay between the points, on average, without reaching them completely.

Comment: @Robert Howard, it seems to be quite so. Thank you!

Comment: You're certainly welcome! I'm going to post an answer about it, too, just so this question doesn't sit in the "unanswered" queue for ages.

Comment: Bezier curves are what you want, trust me. Your comment about Bezier curves not  touching the points exactly just shows that you don't know how they work - you should learn how they work before  rejecting them. In that example plot you posted it looks like you used $C$ and $D$ for "control points" - that's simply not the right way to do it.

Comment: If I have time I'll eventually post something using Bezier curves. First tell me what you'd like the tangent vectors at $A$, $B$, etc to be.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich, you're right, I don't know how Bezier works, but I edited my question to put some example I created from https://www.geogebra.org/m/qcnExXbn

Comment: Did you think about parametric cubic splines ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Bezier curves _are_ cubic splines...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich. Sorry ! I know. I just wanted to mention parametric splines. The word *cubic* was a typo.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Would not the Trapezoidal Method be the best way to put the points together?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I've actually done  a lot of curve drawing "by hand" - all the curves in the  figures in *Complex Made Simple* were drawn using PostScript's curveto function, which is Bezier curves. If you try polynomial interpolation I predict you won't like the results - the curve passing though $p_1,\dots p_n$ has funny wiggles near $p_1$ due to the exact location of the other points.

I don't know what you're talking about when you say Bezier curves don't touch the points. A bezier curve is specified by four points; it passes through two of those points exactly, and the tangent vectors at those two endpoints are determined by the two "control points". The interface in  terms of "control points" makes no sense to me - I wrote code to convert endpoints and tangent vectors at endpoints to endpoints and control points.

You don't say in what sense you want to "draw" this curve. If you want to write PostScript, here's what to do.

Say you  want a curve $c:[0,1]\to\Bbb R^2$ with $c(0)=(x,y)$, $c(1)=(xx,yy)$, $c'(0)=(dx,dy)$ and $c'(1)=(dxx,dyy)$. The following two lines of PostScript give you exactly that:

`x` `y` moveto

`x+dx/3` `y+dy/3` `xx-dxx/`3 `y-dyy/3` `xx` `yy` curveto

Not that text literally - you want strings giving the numeric value of expressions. For exammple if $(x,y)=(0,0)$, $(xx,yy)=(1,1)$, $(dx,dy)=(1,1)$ and $(dxx,dyy)=(2,3)$ you'd say

```
0 0 moveto
0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 1 1 curveto
```

I actually did that to get a curve passing through those points.
Then I found this thing doesn't recognize eps as an image format.
Here's a screen shot.
(This was tedious enough - your points $A,B,\dots$ are just marked
with X's.):

[image]

Comment: I edited my question and put a picture of a Bezier Curve simulation for you to understand. You will notice that the lines are "between" the dots and do not "touch" them ...

Comment: When I said you should use Bezier curves I didn't mean that you'd get good results if you did it totally wrong.

Comment: Sadly, EPS / PostScript is just too powerful to be permitted here. Adobe invented PDF as a safer alternative. But we can't embed PDF here, either. However, we *can* use a more modern file format with vector capabilities: SVG. We can't upload SVG, but if you host the SVG somewhere else, you can link to it and it will get displayed. You can see an example at the end of [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4207568/207316).

Answer (score 2):

Cubic Bezier spline is perfectly suitable 
to smoothly connect the points.

Given an ordered sequence of $n$ points
$p_0,\dots p_{n-1}$, we need to define $n$ 
cubic Bezier segments. 
The points on the $k$-th segment are defined
parametrically as

\begin{align}
s_k(t)=&a_k(1-t)^3+3b_k(1-t)^2t+3c_k(1-t)t^2+d_k t^3
,\quad t\in[0,1]
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

The first and second derivatives of \eqref{1} are given by
\begin{align}
s_k'(t)=&3((b_k-a_k)(1-t)^2+2(c_k-b_k)(1-t)t+(d_k-c_k)t^2)
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
s_k''(t)=&6((a_k-2b_k+c_k)(1-t)+(b_k-2c_k+d_k)t)
\tag{3}\label{3}
.
\end{align}

So, we need to define $a_k,b_k,c_k,d_k$ 
that satisfy 
(all indices here are taken $\mod\,n$):
\begin{align}
s_{k}'(0)=s_{k-1}'(1)&\Rightarrow
&\quad b_k-a_k =&d_{k-1}-c_{k-1}
\\
s_{k+1}'(0)=s_{k}'(1)&\Rightarrow
&\quad b_{k+1}-a_{k+1}=&
d_k-c_k
\\
s_{k}''(0)=s_{k-1}''(1)&\Rightarrow
&\quad c_k-2b_k+a_k=&
 d_{k-1}-2c_{k-1}+b_{k-1}
\end{align}
Excluding $c_{k-1}$ 
and using 
$d_k=a_{k+1}$,
we arrive at $n\times n$ linear system
for $b_k$:
\begin{align}
b_{k-1}+4b_k+b_{k+1}=4a_k+2a_{k+1}
\tag{4}\label{4}
\\
\text{for }k=0,\dots,n-1
.
\end{align}

Then $c_k$ can be easily found:

\begin{align}
c_k&=2a_{k+1}-b_{k+1}
.
\end{align}

Example:

[image]

In case if the curve is not closed, 
you can try this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2835335/122782).

Comment: You should include a plot going thhrough the points in the OP. I can't figure out a way to post my eps file...

Answer (score 1):

A path built from a series of cubic Bézier curves is fine for this application, you just need to add control points between your main points.

A single cubic Bézier curve is defined by its 2 endpoints and 2 control points. The control points lie on the tangents which pass through the endpoints; the distance between an endpoint and its associated control point affects the curvature.

To make a path passing through multiple points, we use a series of Bézier curves, connected at the endpoints, with control points chosen so that the tangents match where the curves connect (otherwise, we get cusps at the connections).

For the example points in the question, we need 5 curves, one from A to B, one from B to C, etc. Since we just have a set of points, with no tangent (or curvature) data, we construct a "default" Bézier path, using each main point's immediate neighbours to determine the tangents. Like this:

[image: Full Bézier path]

The tangent at B is parallel to AC, the tangent at C is parallel to BD, etc. The point A only has 1 neighbour, so we use AB for its tangent. Similarly, the tangent at F is EF.

The distance from a main point to its associated control point is one third of the (straight line) distance between that curve's endpoints. Eg, the distance from B to its left control point is AB/3, and the distance from B to its right control point is BC/3.

See [How to find a bezier curve between two points and two tangents without anchor points](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4173207/207316) for an explanation of the "1/3 rule".

---

Here's the Sage / Python script I used to create that diagram. [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/) is a vast mathematics system built on top of Python. It has nice plotting capabilities (courtesy of matplotlib), and its built-in vector type is handy for this kind of task. If you can read plain Python, (hopefully) you shouldn't have problems reading my script.

```
from itertools import chain 

def bezier_fd(pos):
    "Bezier path plot, using finite differences"
    # Make the normalized tangent vectors
    tgt = [v - u for u, v in zip(pos, pos[2:])]
    if pos[0] == pos[-1]:
        end = [pos[1] - pos[-2]]
        tgt = end + tgt + end
    else:
        tgt = [pos[1] - pos[0]] + tgt + [pos[-1] - pos[-2]]
    tgt = [u.normalized() for u in tgt] 

    # Build Bezier curves
    pos_tgt = zip(pos, tgt)
    p0, t0 = next(pos_tgt)
    row = [p0]
    curves = []
    for p, t in pos_tgt:
        s = abs(p - p0) / 3
        row.extend([p0 + t0*s, p - t*s, p])
        curves.append(row)
        row = []
        p0, t0 = p, t
    return curves 

pos = [
  (0.5, 0.5),
  (1, -0.5),
  (1.5, 1),
  (2.25, 1.1),
  (2.6, -0.5),
  (3, 0.5),
] 

# Plot the main points
pos = [vector(p) for p in pos]
P = points(pos, color="blue") 

# Label the points
ne = vector((0.1, 0.1))
nw = vector((-0.1, 0.1))
offsets = (nw, nw, nw, ne, ne, ne)
P += sum(text(c, p + delta)
  for c, p, delta in zip("ABCDEF", pos, offsets)) 

# Compute & plot the bezier curves
curves = bezier_fd(pos)
P += bezier_path(curves, color="red") 

# The main points & the control points in a flat list
pts = list(chain.from_iterable(curves)) 

# The tangents
P += sum(line(t, color="#333", linestyle="--")
  for t in chain([pts[:2]], zip(pts[2::3], pts[4::3]), [pts[-2:]])) 

# The rest of the hull
P += sum(line(t, color="#333", linestyle=":")
  for t in zip(pts[1::3], pts[2::3])) 

# The control points
P += points([p for i, p in enumerate(pts) if i%3], color="magenta") 

P.show(xmin=0, aspect_ratio=1, ticks=(0.5, 0.5), gridlines="minor")
```

Here's a [live version of the script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyVVMGOmzAQvfMVI1atcEMoSdoeInHobttTK-2htwhFDpjEWmMjbJJ2v74zNpBkb41EZM-M37x5Hk_TmxakE70zRlmQbWd6B9WJSw1RVIsGDuJVin7f1ElnLNtGgL_40Ruh4-4EnTIuhcFKfYRGagSDWjaN6IWuhI39gQf4xV8EuJMAbfqWK_kqanBcH4V2cBaVM731ke7ooIDdGZYwQGN6GFI4A7J5lR0xSAH_duttyUofLxtvyEsoCr9arspAkn5C14RG9lWJkD5gXZZzQEhHYQu_XtDae4WyYvsm7h4oL8v51G5M_TbHeG7IrmUnLNRFRaG7RJ2DRI-DVDWM0lZDfxZBEgTcB5xZA9yy4Mtxk6NLiz8uGSODqzcXTzkPTAIgWcKeOHR4mGiM567lUhw_2KSjenIGH2Ez-xA3w2SoU4LgpED-ga4FQ51flGyODUkz3nUUjifZLcyVzF0pxCpUINzQ64l5FCFNOoK-JM8-p4B_LKXdKoXldUOuVVivszVtsnn75TZyM0HQHTzAMzayb9GWe02kdnbKGVo06cLddaNoZfRMfH1kuJjKKNMX8UENImYe9Sc_COVhR0Qt8MyIh3WsiMSKsUhfbuzLG4dpGisc0Uj0JYX5E9PHkMaiADu0iaM2qOg2FlAL5TgJTpTJlgbT9Jrir49P377_iP2TSmFMwwLtJ9N2Az7l9_59e_6Hu86c--l-QAQqo43mQxICZ2l6UY_K_L6XGlNRlspo1xs1GdHNoVHcgZLWRZ3XgZaJH1JZgwNsTwOMH5QYc7Er_jhi7FUhJbVI3EznYbPZoAJkte6vEkW8XMaTaP5x-DzY6s7utvis0_AKHQ2h7Qa3tPxES5aCj1ridCpvOPSIjOr66k6DUv_BZXtPZcq8umb2JG6S3csXUo0Nuus8kkxD_wo9tCibEwTJaJDKd4Q6kmk5Ccf9XT1n9mQuyZ9W6gJfKbcdtukez0pTYJs6Wb3Y4uZNwrGXtS8DcSSOvpj9A4lH4AU=&lang=sage), running on the SageMathCell server.

And here's an SVG version of the basic path, without visible control points, etc.

[image: Basic Bézier path, SVG]
[Source code](https://gist.github.com/PM2Ring/6ae38b93c038fecc4f1bf3fa3269715f?short_path=b50fc79)

Just for fun, here's a single [interactive Bézier curve](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJylVt1u2zYUvvdTcOpFJESRHbdGg8RO0SXZMCBZgyUrGhS5YCTaIkqRGnVkSxvyQHuOvdgOSSmR5LhrMQO2TJ6P5-c7HynOfzj_cHZ7d31BUsjE6WjePhhN8JExoCROqS4YLLwSlgdHHk4DB8FObz7-TH785-8_OdPzsZsazQuoBSM8WXhZbf8jPuY6xsm_RgQ_BWj1hR2TV9Pp9KQzc7DhCaTHZBLNetMqpzGH2himjWXJhejOv8X5x1GUlkIMg8xms28JktACi9QU3U3J9DnKMZFKMuv9gZlCh_4nk8lL_g9fcjEfW0KQpHFD74NKasPZekXWTBdcyYV3GE08UmVCFgsvBciPx-PNZhNtXkdKr8ZTDDhGvIf-15xtHlS18CZkQtBgvt74dIT-W8ex5jmcjtZUExNkQRIVlxmTEP1RMl3fMMFiUNr3jMsgRKeQcrkqEPn53gwTTVfnFEWwaCoHqlcMsCgkOySqQi7xUduHG5j_o8eT0WhZyhiwJpLRL-xcgV-hMSQ6JLESSgeNx1jJAgjtJhdrRoFdCGZGv974mF0kacYK7Dn7_bdfQrLnNLUXOKJphAJ9D6D5QwnM9-LKw3R2GWs01juMGm16h82002uzb9qOmdE8ZzI5S7lIfPq0lCbJxRrTv-QFMMmQ40yVBUvURqIPJW-QSQjJkoqCfWURqDJOC4Pdtcp1LMrLIrXhHwfMX1NI_VgUJvGEFf-P9hyd7SRd0KIw_IjiCZGgdhAV2dAYyz6dsczR6LKj_8Hm10rsuMn7tbUx834WzqVgQBInbM9rdqvSxDfzfDE5IXz-Bn_29wNrMx8L329qiMyp-B58HpB9ZBA-3fkuy8_83kx5pPGaD1hKkCHjaVCGc0HbCjSDUkskMK6iB8z9IxXRmoqSRaB-4hVL_NcYxaW2F-5hQITWO6H9WEjzteISUF9sDUPSlE4Ma2iJrPiQw3fd0efJPTk2EyedZTngEsk25PzDlfXtO0dRLDiK6VNIeuO7prFNmTlEGUWGqltNZYF9yHwb0J41EX5vUJpMnt1e-UHEpTkrmR8Mqmo2R7ckviR-e4I13p7b6WJ3i4AVtIVbbNfGi1tTfmuvc0YWKJ3O9mykuoLtXdwuftcsyNSaeUiiOxLsKHzKS8krnBjs8W_xitvm2WmZ91xeyKTvsdO2gRycfUAbwjCHgUlVZndBVJEDm-FQq0N47eB1C6-H8G478TTJcl-GRKiQpHywMa5wv6NmKt9Y3YBLg0bkli4Mn11ZmA7mmhkyz9mSlgL84PtIMYW7BJvyO5yE5iWIr-Lhmrq7pu6tqQdrNLYSA28Vgl0c1tHsEW1V1NfHU_u3FWul8h1q3CkKcw3oZ9nm3jtV3M4aLH-W9lA4XWzVgdW7YfXWS6U5jt_cB7tMs3vHsP-U_CBtjREOm-tge4mZ2k7Za4z3is1mXtC3Hx71APRlgP2xiNlyCzHtAd4eLbsAW4Bn7rr4IvGuLi8vt63urmrtZ8b6GBgt4f2zuQ_iBdRe8_8FTU-qOA==&lang=html). You can drag points around and watch what happens. (It should work with a mouse or touchscreen). You can run it on the server, or [download](https://gist.github.com/PM2Ring/25c503092bca5b4444a1112d2d1ca59b) it to run it locally.

Comment: I realise this question is a few years old, but it's not easy to find simple, solid info on how to make a Bézier path when you don't have tangent data.

Answer (score 0):

Given an arbitrary set of $n$ points, it's possible to find the equation of a unique polynomial of degree at most $n-1$ that passes through all $n$ points.

---

Let's consider a very simple example; say we we wanted to find the parabola that passes through the points $(-4,2)$, $(-2,-1)$, and $(1,1)$.

The general equation of a parabola is $$y=ax^2+bx+c$$ so we can substitute the $x$- and $y$-coordinates of the three points we have to create a system of three equations with three unknowns, like so:
$$\begin{align}
2&=16a-4b+c \\
-1&=4a-2b+c \\
1&=a+b+c
\end{align}$$
Solving this system, we find that $a=\frac{13}{30}$, $b=\frac{11}{10}$, and $c=\frac{-8}{15}$. The parabola $y=\frac{13}{30}x^2+\frac{11}{10}x-\frac{8}{15}$ does indeed pass cleanly through all three points, so we're done.

---

And of course, you could do this with a system of six equations with six unknowns as well, but that would just take a little longer than this example.

**Edit:**

Mathematica reveals that the interpolating polynomial for those six points is approximately
$$y=1.51771x^5-10.5198x^4+23.6478x^3-17.2688x^2-0.696339x+2.81946$$
The graph of that function looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you actually _done_ this, with more than three points? In my experience interpolating polynomials don't give the results one wants here  - they have funny wiggles in funny directions.

Comment: I admit I've never used interpolation to find anything higher than a third-degree polynomial, but it's always worked well for me in those relatively simple cases. What do you mean by "funny wiggles?"

Comment: Take the points in his figure, find the interpolating polynomial and draw it - you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Come on! I went to some trouble to make an eps file showing what the Bezier looks like - show us what you get using polynomial interpolation..

Comment: I see how one could call the local extrema "funny wiggles," but it does connect the points in a smooth way, like the OP asked for. If, on the other hand, he was really after a closed curve all along, then I agree that polynomial interpolation is certainly not the way to go.

Comment: Suppose you're interpolating $f(t)$ from finitely many sampled points. Say your samples are $f(0)=f(1)=f(2)=f(3)=f(4)=0$, $f(5)=10$. Would $f(1/2)=3.28$ be a reasonable hypothesis for $f(1/2)$, or would it be more reasonable to think that $f$ is much flatter on $(0,4)$, making $f(1/2)$ much smaller? (Or say it's a graphics application where the user draws a curve by clicking on a few points in order and it draws a curve through those points. Say the user clicks on $(0,0), (1,0), (2,0),(3,0),(4,0),(5,10)$. Is the user really hoping to see something like a damped sine wave?)

Comment: I never claimed that polynomial interpolation is the best curve-fitting technique there is, nor will I pretend that it works perfectly in every scenario. Granted, I've never learned about Bezier curves, so polynomial interpolation is the best curve-fitting technique I'm familiar with. Even in that example, however, the interpolating polynomial is quite flat; $f(1/2)$ is about $0.27$: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lelbazgfio

Answer (score 0):

I created my own code to generate what you're looking for using the math in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WCGKqJrf4N4

I required this code for a flutter project using Dart.

```
class LinearInterpolationPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<double> data;
  final double spacing;

  LinearInterpolationPainter({
    this.data = const [],
    this.spacing,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    
    //Used to determine the pixels between each data point
    double _spacing = spacing ?? size.width / (data.length - 1);

    var paint = Paint();
    // TODO: Set properties to paint

    paint.color = Colors.green.shade800;
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    paint.strokeWidth = 2.0;

    var path = Path();

    /// Set the path to initial data point
    path.moveTo(0, size.height - data[0]);

    // Draw path
    for (int x = 0; x < data.length - 1; x++) {
      for (int space = 0; space < _spacing; space++) {
        path.lineTo(
          (x * _spacing) + space,
          size.height - interpolate(x + (space / _spacing)),
        );
      }
    }

    /// Draw path to final data point
    path.lineTo(
      (data.length - 1) * _spacing,
      size.height - data.last,
    );

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }

  /// Calculates the y-value for an x-value given a set of points
  double interpolate(double a) {
    double result = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
      double product = data[j];

      for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (i != j) product *= (a - i) / (j - i);
      }

      result += product;
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```